# Rails memory leak due to all function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks

So i keep getting a memory leak. I believe its because i have a table in my view that shows the whole database (whole database being 23k rows)

Is there any method i could use without getting a memory leak on heroku constantly?

Heres what i have

```
  def index
    @newevents = Event.order("id").page(params[:page]).per(100)
    @ready = Event.all
  end
```

I cant tell which one is causing the issue, However i also haven't thought about making the 'Event.all' paginated whgich may fix it a bit?

Sam

**Edit**

View

```
<h1>Events To Do</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>EventName</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @newevents.each do |ne| %>
      <% if ne.eventready.blank?%>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ne.id %></td>
        <td><%= ne.eventname %></td>
        <td><%= ne.date %></td>
        <td><%= ne.time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit Event", edit_event_path(ne.id), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>

    </tbody>
  </table>
<%= paginate @newevents %>
<h1>Events Made</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>EventName</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @ready.each do |co| %>
      <% if co.eventready.present?%>
      <tr>
        <td><%= co.id %></td>
        <td><%= co.eventname %></td>
        <td><%= co.date %></td>
        <td><%= co.time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit Event", edit_event_path(co.id), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: What do you use `@ready` for?

Comment: Another table on the same page, Its just checking to see if event.complete is present

Comment: Can you include the code? maybe be minimising the amount of data sent you can make it work

Comment: Will add it now, ^_^

Comment: So what is the question here? If you paginate `@newevents` then why not do the same for the other table?